# Trying to get Webauthn running

Tags: delphi, webauthn

I've started a [Fido2/WebAuthn](https://github.com/mikerabat/DelphiFido2) project a while ago and tried to get microsofts webauthn implementation starting. For this in this project there exists a
translation of the [webauthn.h](https://github.com/microsoft/webauthn/blob/master/webauthn.h) file
(as today I only found refernces to this file in Mozilla and Chromium browsers code...).

Now ... I simply tried to create form with a button issuing a command to create credentials but
this call fails miserably with an access violation @ $0000EA60 and I have no clue what that might cause. What might I do wrong???

Here the code for a button onClick handler.

```
uses Webauthn;

// just a test JSON object that I obtained from a browser request
const cClientData : UTF8String = '{' +
 '"hashAlgorithm": "SHA-256",' +
 '"challenge": "fzjg31IEKi6ZxKqsQ9S_XHG9WvdmcXPah5EXd11p1bU",' +
 '"origin": "https:\/\/fidotest.com",' +
 '"clientExtensions": {},' +
 '"type": "webauthn.create"' +
 '}';

procedure TfrmWebAuthnTest.btnCredentialClick(Sender: TObject);
var RpInformation : TWebAuthnRPEntityInformation; // _In_
    UserInformation : TWebAuthUserEntityInformation; // _In_
    PubKeyCredParams : TWebauthnCoseCredentialParameters; // _In_
    WebAuthNClientData : TWebAuthnClientData; // _In_
    WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions : TWebAuthnAuthenticatorMakeCredentialOptions; // _In_opt_
    pWebAuthNCredentialAttestation : PWEBAUTHN_CREDENTIAL_ATTESTATION; // _Outptr_result_maybenull_
    hr : HRESULT;
    coseParams : Array[0..1] of WEBAUTHN_COSE_CREDENTIAL_PARAMETER;
    i : integer;
    challenge : Array[0..31] of byte;
    cancellationID : TGuid;
    bufClientData : UTF8String;
begin
     // ################################################
     // #### relying party
     FillChar(RpInformation, sizeof(RpInformation), 0);
     RpInformation.dwVersion := WEBAUTHN_RP_ENTITY_INFORMATION_CURRENT_VERSION;
     RpInformation.pwszId := 'fidotest.com';
     RpInformation.pwszName := 'Sweet home localhost';
     RpInformation.pwszIcon := nil;

     // ################################################
     // #### user information
     FillChar(UserInformation, sizeof(UserInformation), 0);
     UserInformation.dwVersion := WEBAUTHN_USER_ENTITY_INFORMATION_CURRENT_VERSION;
     UserInformation.cbId := sizeof( challenge );

     Randomize;

     // create credentials
     for i := 0 to Length(challenge) - 1 do
     begin
          challenge[i] := Byte( Random(High(byte) + 1) );
     end;

     UserInformation.pbId := @challenge[0];
     UserInformation.pwszName := 'Mike';
     UserInformation.pwszIcon := niL;
     UserInformation.pwszDisplayName := 'Mike Rabat';

     // ################################################
     // #### Client data
     bufClientData := Copy( cClientData, 1, Length(cClientData));
     FillChar(WebAuthNClientData, sizeof(WebAuthNClientData), 0);
     WebAuthNClientData.dwVersion := WEBAUTHN_CLIENT_DATA_CURRENT_VERSION;
     WebAuthNClientData.cbClientDataJSON := Length(cClientData);
     WebAuthNClientData.pbClientDataJSON := PAnsiChar(bufClientData);
     WebAuthNClientData.pwszHashAlgId := WEBAUTHN_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA_256;

     // ################################################
     // #### pub ked credential params
     PubKeyCredParams.cCredentialParameters := sizeof(coseParams);
     PubKeyCredParams.pCredentialParameters := @coseParams[0];

     coseParams[0].dwVersion := WEBAUTHN_COSE_CREDENTIAL_PARAMETER_CURRENT_VERSION;
     coseParams[0].pwszCredentialType := WEBAUTHN_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_PUBLIC_KEY;
     coseParams[0].lAlg := WEBAUTHN_COSE_ALGORITHM_ECDSA_P256_WITH_SHA256;

     coseParams[1].dwVersion := WEBAUTHN_COSE_CREDENTIAL_PARAMETER_CURRENT_VERSION;
     coseParams[1].pwszCredentialType := WEBAUTHN_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_PUBLIC_KEY;
     coseParams[1].lAlg := WEBAUTHN_COSE_ALGORITHM_RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_WITH_SHA256;

     // ###########################################
     // #### Fill in params
     FillChar(WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions, sizeof(WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions), 0);
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.dwVersion := WEBAUTHN_AUTHENTICATOR_MAKE_CREDENTIAL_OPTIONS_CURRENT_VERSION;
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.dwTimeoutMilliseconds := 60000;
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.bRequireResidentKey := False;
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.dwAuthenticatorAttachment := WEBAUTHN_AUTHENTICATOR_ATTACHMENT_CROSS_PLATFORM;
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.dwUserVerificationRequirement := WEBAUTHN_USER_VERIFICATION_REQUIREMENT_REQUIRED;
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.dwAttestationConveyancePreference := WEBAUTHN_ATTESTATION_CONVEYANCE_PREFERENCE_DIRECT;

     // ###########################################
     // #### Cancellation
     assert( WebAuthNGetCancellationId(cancellationID) = S_OK, 'Cancellation ID failed');
     WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions.pCancellationId := @cancellationID;

     // ###########################################
     // #### do the magic
     pWebAuthNCredentialAttestation := nil;
     hr := WebAuthNAuthenticatorMakeCredential( Handle,
                                                @RpInformation,
                                                @UserInformation,
                                                @PubKeyCredParams,
                                                @WebAuthNClientData,
                                                @WebAuthNMakeCredentialOptions,
                                                pWebAuthNCredentialAttestation );

     if hr = S_OK then
     begin
          // WriteCredAttest( pWebAuthNCredentialAttestation );

          WebAuthNFreeCredentialAttestation( pWebAuthNCredentialAttestation );
          memLog.Lines.Add('Finished');
     end
     else
     begin
          memLog.Lines.Add('Make Cred failed with: ' + WebAuthNGetErrorName( hr ));
     end;
end;
```

I'm using Delphi2010 so all strings should be unicode except the JSON client data string.

Comment: I've only played with this in a browser context but the github readme for webauthn.h does list a contact email: fido-dev@microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lengthy study of the C++ code of the Mozilla Browser I think I found the problem.
It was in the size field of the COSE_PARAMS structure.

```
 // #### pub ked credential params
 PubKeyCredParams.cCredentialParameters := Length(coseParams);// sizeof(coseParams);
 PubKeyCredParams.pCredentialParameters := @coseParams[0];
```

Instead of the size in bytes they seem to expect the length of the array of the
attached coseParams. That misunderstanding led to the AV.